# How to remove database name from the user/schema name in oracle after migration from SQL Server to Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

We are migrating our database from SQL Server to Oracle using the SQL developer tool. While migration, the schema name in SQL Server is "**schmdw**". This schema is used in our datawarehouse or OLAP database **AdvworksDW**. After migration we were expecting the schema/user name in oracle will be **schmdw**. But it is coming as **schmdw_AdvworksDW** i.e. schemaname_databasename. How can we get rid of this and get the schema/user name in Oracle as **schmdw** only? Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: how did you migrate it? SQL Developer should have created a new user called 'SCHMDW' to match what you had in SQL Server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith to answer your question, what you have said is not happening actually. Instead the new user getting created in Oracle db is having name in the format of schemaname_OLAPDBName (particularly for non-"dbo" users). For "dbo" user the new user getting created in Oracle db is having just the OLAPDBName.  Now we have taken care of this scenario by using the suggestion given below, and we have explicitly created users dbo, user1,user2 and so on. By OLAPDBName I have meant the OLAP Database name in SQL Server side before migration.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, there's no supported way to rename a schema/user. The best solution for you is to create another user, SCHMDW in your case, and give it grants on all objects of the SCHMDW_ADVWORKSDW plus synonyms. Have a look at the second comment on [this post](https://heliodias.wordpress.com/2007/11/15/cookbook-for-rename-owner/#comments), it gives a pl/sql script to automate that.